# How to retrieve a list of devices connected to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, application-development, devices

Is there is an API to retrieve the list of devices connected to the Ubuntu One service?

Answer (score 1):

At [Ubuntu One Account Page](https://one.ubuntu.com/account/) you can see the list and remove linked devices.

Obviously, API is here: [UbuntuOne Admin API](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/index)

Hovewer, [there (*Account info API* )](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/account_info/cloud) such or at least identical feature is not listed.

Anyway for creating full access method to your account you should follow this note:
[***Issue OAuth Tokens – Cloud: Methods***](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud)

Comment: I also looked into the API docs and didn't found anything about devices, but Software Center Sync and Ubuntu One client, even old, GTK based, retrieving the list of devices somehow :)

Comment: I think anyway for full access method you should follow this:
[Issue OAuth Tokens – Cloud: Methods](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud) ... Alternatively, you can download source of Ubuntu One client and try to find method in the code ) Good Luck in hacking!

Comment: @wik: Neither of those pieces of software download a list of authorised devices.  Instead, they contain code to acquire a new authorisation token for access to the API (which makes them show up in the list of authorised clients).  More information can be found at https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/index

Comment: as is no one mention there, some about "devicelist" feature ...
right ... but apps and pages can have full access. It means method exist, but through OAuth token only.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no public API for retrieving the list of devices programmatically. As noted above users can edit and unapprove devices from the U1 website or from the control panel.